# VB.NET updating SQL Database Command

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I am building an asp.net web application using vb and .net 2.0.  I have a class that handles an object and all its attributes.  This class correctly handles reading, creating, and deleting from the database.  However, it will not update.  I took the update script directly from the Microsoft SQL database, but I cannot figure it out.  Here is my SQL command.

```
saveCommand = "UPDATE [Database].[Table] SET [name] = @name,[content] = @content,[date_updated] = @dateupdated WHERE ref = @ref"
```

This is then being put into...

```
Dim setCmd As New SqlCommand(saveCommand, sqlConn)
```

And then parameter values are put into it.  It is weird because the "saveCommand" is determined on whether the item already exists (updates) or doesn't (switches to "INSERT INTO" command WHICH WORKS)

More Code

```
Public Class MyClass()
    #Region Properties
        Public name As String = ""
        Public content As String = ""
        Public date_updated As DateTime = DateTime.Now
    #End Region

    Public Sub Save()
    Dim sqlConn As New SqlConnection(sqlConnString)

    sqlConn.Open()

    Dim saveCommand As String
    If Me.Exists Then
        saveCommand = "UPDATE [Database].[Table] SET [name] = @name,[content] = @content,[date_updated] = @date_updated WHERE ref = @ref"
    Else
        saveCommand = "INSERT INTO [Database].[Table] ([name],[content],[date_updated],[ref]) VALUES(@name,@content,@date_updated,@ref)"
    End If

    Dim setCmd As New SqlCommand(saveCommand, sqlConn)
    setCmd.Parameters.Add("@name", Data.SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Me.name
    setCmd.Parameters.Add("@content", Data.SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Me.content
    setCmd.Parameters.Add("@date_updated", Data.SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = Me.date_updated

    If Me.Exists Then
        setCmd.Parameters.Add("@ref", Data.SqlDbType.Int).Value = Me.ID
    Else
        Dim countCmd As New SqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [DWM-DataSQL].[dbo].[biglots]", sqlConn)
        Me.ID = countCmd.ExecuteScalar() + 1
        setCmd.Parameters.Add("@ref", Data.SqlDbType.Int).Value = Me.ID
        Me.Exists = True
    End If

    setCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    sqlConn.Close()
    sqlConn.Dispose()
End Sub

Public Sub New()
End Sub

Public Sub New(ByVal num As Integer)
    Me.ID = num
End Sub

End Class
```

This is being called upon by

```
myObj = New BLL.MyClass(ref)

'When form is submitted
Public Sub submitForm(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
   myObj.name = tbName.Text
   myObj.content = tbcontent.Text
   myObj.Save()
End Sub
```

Comment: Please post all the code relative to your operation. When you say _it doesn't update_ it means that the record is not changed or that you get an error message?

Comment: I've just realized the only thing that successfully updates is the [date_updated] field

Comment: So actually the update works. Then you should post the code where you assign the values to the parameters. And have a look at the part where you got the values from. I guess it's a bug in your ASP.NET code.

Comment: @TimSchmelter I understand that but I don't know why my other values aren't going in.  The subitForm() sub is the same one that I use to create a new row and it takes those values fine.  Do I have to assign them another way?

Comment: What is the code of Me.Exists?

Comment: Me.Exists is under #Region Properties.  It is a Boolean defined as "Me.Exists as Boolean = False".  There is a private sub before the save sub called Read() that will check the database passed on the Me.ID passed to see if it exists.  If it exists than the values are put in to the proper variable and Me.Exists changes to true.

Comment: Side-note: you should not count rows to determine the next ID. That is a  race condition and also very slow. Instead use  auto increment by making `ref` an [`IDENTITY`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186775.aspx) column.

Comment: You have two different version of UPDATE the first contains SET for the first field, the second one miss that keyword. It is just a typo?

Comment: @Steve I apologize thats just a typo.  I cant realize the real values so I had to put in different ones.

Comment: @TimSchmelter I am new to ASP.NET and will doing this eventually once its working.

Comment: @nwestfall: if that is just a typo you're not showing the real code. So what code are you showing?

Comment: @TimSchmelter I am showing real code just with different values and database names.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.  It was somehow calling upon the read() function RIGHT before the save() function so it replaced all the values. Thanks Anyway